# "Sphere ---> Circle, Ball---> ?"

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, geometry

I am struggling with a puzzle in Swedish. I will translate it to English:

> 6. Sphere ---> Circle, Ball--->?
>
> - a) Sphere
> - b) Ring
> - c) Circle
> - d) ?

The answer provided is "It is hottest that Ring is correct based on a 3D/2D perspective or if you convert the objects into other alternatives to things that are "handled" with similar geometric shapes..."

To give a bit more context, the puzzle is asking for the word that can replace "Ball" in the same way that "Circle" replaces "Sphere". The possible answers are "Sphere", "Ring", "Circle", and an unknown option.

I have been trying to solve this puzzle, but I'm not sure where to start. I have considered the different geometric properties of the shapes and their relationships, but I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Here is where I found the puzzle:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/869145673197580298/1083855309942030346/PIL_-_sammanfattning_av_fragor_oscar_bakhouch.doc

Comment: A ring could be considered a generalisation of a circle. It also could’ve been a mistranslation because ‘It is hottest that (this)’ does not make sense in English.

Comment: What do you mean by the first statement?

Comment: Sphere and circle are mathematical concepts.  A Ball is a physical object that has the shape of a sphere.  So the answer would be a physical object that has the shape of a circle, that is a ring.

Comment: @FlorianF Ball is also a mathematical object, namely the interior of a sphere. A sphere is the surface of a ball. The answer would then be disc, which is the interior of a circle.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks. I suspected it could be the case, I am more familiar with the french terms.  In this case, ring is listed but not disk, so I would go for the ring.  I also think that real objects is what the OP means by "things that are "handled"".

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I am not convinced, I was taught in elementary school that the circle is the area inside the circumfetence, which is the boundary of such area

Comment: @jarmanso7 Jaap is correct. In higher math, for example real analysis, "circle" refers to the boundary and "disk" refers to the interior.

Comment: @jarmanso7 I was taught in elementary school to never subtract a larger number from a smaller one. Here's more on mathematical balls and spheres: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ball.html; https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenBall.html; https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html; and even the https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HairyBallTheorem.html, which, as a math joke, is formulated as “there does not exist a 3-cow without at least one cowlick.” It's kinda true (since _n_-cow is isomorphic to an _n_-ball) for any odd _n._ Another possible reasoning is that _n_-cow is isomorphic to _n_-torus. :-)

Comment: I can do a better translation, but I'm entirely unfamiliar with the maths terminology in Swedish.  “Answer: Most likely, ‘ring’ is the right answer from the 3D/2D perspective, or if you relate objects that you can "handle" [physical objects? -kkm] to those with similar geometric shapes  [geometric objects? -kkm] in the second {case/choice/alternative}.” Still unclear what is the "second case" _(det andra alternativet),_ probably a reference to the "Boll--->?" part, but I'm not sure. The original seems either poorly worded or laced with geometry terms. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Isn't the answer just

> "Disk/Disc"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics)

Because:

> Sphere is the shell, like Circle. Ball is the volume surrounded by a Sphere, and Disc is the area surrounded by a Circle?

Answer (score 1):

As someone studying topology, though I might be overthinking this, I would say the answer is:

> Two spheres conjoined by a point.

The action done to the shapes might be:

> To exclude two points and get an [absolute retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)) of the resulting space.

Though, this explanation assumes that:

> The ball is an open ball. That means, the ball has its boundary excluded.

If this is really the answer, we can speculate what would happen to other shapes as well. For example:

> A torus would become the wedge of three circles.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is based on:

> Cross Section

If you:

> Cut a **solid** sphere in half, the cross section will be a circle.

However, if you:

> Cut a **hollow** ball in half, and the cross section will be a ring.
>  (ball doesn't necessarily mean hollow in english, but it could be a translation issue)

Comment: "Cut a hollow ball in half, and the cross section will be a ring."

Could you elaborate why? I can't picture it in my head.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense but assumes significant translation issues - that the word translated "sphere" actually means "ball" and vice versa, that the word translated "circle" actually means "disc", and that the word translated "ring" actually means "circle".

Comment: I mean, the answer can be anything you want if you give "sphere", "circle", "ball" and "ring" colloquial, non-rigorous, and arbitrary definitions. Mathematically, spheres aren't solid, circles aren't filled, balls aren't hollow, and rings aren't two-dimensional.